# How do I do transition between same level hardwood and tile floors?

Tags: trim, finish, title

[How do I install transition molding between my new hardwood and existing tile floors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-do-i-install-transition-molding-between-my-new-hardwood-and-existing-tile-fl) has the floor and tile at different heights. What if they are the same level? Do I even need to do anything different on the vs between the titles?

I have a 5'x5' section of floor I'm changing from faux hardwood to tile.

This example picture is the 12"x12" test tile I set in place.

[image: Test single square.]

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/40707/18078

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a nice straight, square cut of the wood at the edge of the tile, I'd just use some caulk that matches the grout color, between "wood" and tile.